# C# - How to print image (png) file directly to wifi printer using Sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, printing, network-printers

I am currently using this code which sends raw data or .txt file to a network printer(Wi-Fi) successfully.

```
    public class PrintHelper
    {
        private readonly IPAddress PrinterIPAddress;

        private readonly byte[] FileData;

        private readonly int PortNumber;
        private ManualResetEvent connectDoneEvent { get; set; }

        private ManualResetEvent sendDoneEvent { get; set; }

        public PrintHelper(byte[] fileData, string printerIPAddress, int portNumber = 9100)
        {
            FileData = fileData;
            PortNumber = portNumber;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(printerIPAddress, out PrinterIPAddress))
                throw new Exception("Wrong IP Address!");
        }

        public PrintHelper(byte[] fileData, IPAddress printerIPAddress, int portNumber = 9100)
        {
            FileData = fileData;
            PortNumber = portNumber;
            PrinterIPAddress = printerIPAddress;
        }

        /// <inheritDoc />
        public bool PrintData()
        {
            //this line is Optional for checking before send data
            if (!NetworkHelper.CheckIPAddressAndPortNumber(PrinterIPAddress, PortNumber))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PING FAILED");
                return false;
            }
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(PrinterIPAddress, PortNumber);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.NoDelay = true;

            connectDoneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            sendDoneEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            try
            {
                client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(connectCallback), client);
                connectDoneEvent.WaitOne();
                client.BeginSend(FileData, 0, FileData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(sendCallback), client);
                sendDoneEvent.WaitOne();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Shutdown the client
                this.shutDownClient(client);
            }
        }

        private void connectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDoneEvent.Set();
        }

        private void sendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDoneEvent.Set();
        }
        private void shutDownClient(Socket client)
        {
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
    }


    public static class NetworkHelper
    {
        public static bool CheckIPAddressAndPortNumber(IPAddress ipAddress, int portNumber)
        {
            return PingIPAddress(ipAddress) && CheckPortNumber(ipAddress, portNumber);
        }
        public static bool PingIPAddress(IPAddress iPAddress)
        {
            var ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(iPAddress);

            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                //Server is alive
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        public static bool CheckPortNumber(IPAddress iPAddress, int portNumber)
        {
            var retVal = false;
            try
            {
                using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect(iPAddress, portNumber);
                    retVal = tcpClient.Connected;
                    tcpClient.Close();
                }
                return retVal;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return retVal;
            }

        }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("sample.txt");   //SUCCESS
        //byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("QR.png");     /* Not Working */
        

        PrintHelper print = new PrintHelper(fileBytes, "192.168.1.9", 9100);
        bool result = print.PrintData();
        if (result == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAILURE");
        }

    }
```

I am trying to print image file (.png) by replacing the text path, it prints junk characters on top of A4 sheets.

Searched in google, its says to use PrintDocument function and Graphics but the printer is not connected to system and we are not using any drivers.

I couldn't find a code to print image file through sockets.

I am using HP M202dw Laser printer and it is connected by WiFi.

What am I missing? Please help

Comment: It's not enough to the send the image data. You need to also send PCL (Printer Control Language), PS (Postscript), Espon ESC/P or Canon UFR commands to the printer to tell it how to render the image data. Which kind of commands you need depend on the printer and how it is configured. This is why people use drivers.

Comment: Isn't there a way to print without drivers?

Comment: Yes. You send all the control language commands manually. But that means knowing what control language to use, and what commands you need. It's not trivial. Drivers exist for a reason.